# How to send data to kafka topic with kafka sink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Currently I have a sink connector which gets data from topic A and sends its to an external service.

Now I have a use case when based on some logic I should send it to topic B instead of the service.
And this logic based on the response of the target service,that will return response based on the data.
So because the data should be sent to the target system every time I couldnt use the stream api.

Is that feasible somehow?

Or should I add a kafka producer manually to my sink? If so is there any drawback?

Answer (score 0):

The first option, is to create a [custom Kafka Connect Single Message Transform](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/custom.html) that will implement the desired logic and possibly use [`ExtractTopic`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/extracttopic.html#extracttopic) as well (depending on how your custom smt looks like).

---

The second option is to build your own consumer. For example:

**Step 1: Create one more topic on top of topic A**

Create one more topic, say `topic_a_to_target_system`

**Step 2: Implement your custom consumer**

Implement a Kafka Consumer that consumes all the messages from topic `topic_a`. 
At this point, you need to instantiate a Kafka Producer and based on the logic, decide whether the topic needs to be forwarded to `topic_B` or to the target system (`topic_a_to_target_system`).

**Step 3: Start Sink connector on `topic_a_to_target_system`**

Finally start your sink connector so that it sinks the data from topic `topic_a_to_target_system` to your target system.

Comment: These dont work because the logic is based on the external service. So first every record should be sent to this service. And based on the response we either done with the task or we should store the record in other kafka topic also.

Comment: I'm looking for a way of sending the data from Sink Connector to Kafka topic (AVRO format). Anyone did it so far?